# Wirecloud widgets - Unit test

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

which tools can be used to make unit test on Wirecloud widgets and operators?

Any of Javascript testing frameworks are valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any JavaScript framework for unit testing WireCloud widgets and operators. You can find a mock of the API provided by WireCloud in this [repo](https://github.com/Wirecloud/mock-applicationmashup). You can also take a look into some of the [Widgets](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/kurento-one2one-widget) using this mock (jointly with jasmine).